# How to make the background of ”TextEdit“ transparent?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, textedit

Today I tried to modify the "backcolor" of my controls "TextEdit". it's an editor of DevExpress. When I entered the properties and started changing the background color to transparent, the "backcolor" of text change nothing but the color of the space in the inner margin had changed. So how can I make the effect of transparent background?

[image]

Comment: [winforms](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit._properties)? [wpf](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.TextEdit)? In any case consider to add [mcve].

Comment: Winforms, thx for prompt :)

Comment: There are plenty of questions on this on DevExpress forums. Unfortunately this is not supported. This might help though: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/e3225/how-to-create-a-transparent-textedit

Comment: It really helps me a lot!!!♥ THX